Record keeping of Catholic sacraments worldwide
Just gone through the sacrament of marriage in the US and one thing that I learned here is that they expect the parishes where my wife and I were baptized at to have record of all our sacraments; and that if we had done communion and confirmation in different parishes they would have let our baptismal parishes known. Even every Google search that I make regarding this (mostly from US and Europe) mention the same thing, and for a marriage or confirmation to go under the radar of the parish of baptism is an exceptional event. For example... this stackexchange post: How does the Catholic Church handle documents worldwide nowadays?
Well, my wife and I were both baptized and confirmed in the Philippines. With the pretext presented by the parish here in the US (as well as my Google searches), I had my aunt help us get annotated baptismal certificates from our parishes in our home country. As it turns out, the baptismal parishes do NOT have any record of our confirmation because they were not done in the same parish -- and my aunt had to go to the parishes where we had our confirmation just go get certificates for those.
So my question is... if record keeping of sacraments between parishes is supposedly part of canon law (as per my Google searches as well), why doesn't it seem to be a universal thing? It was a roller coaster ride finding these out during marriage prep, and had we not allotted enough time for it then it would've caused significant delays. We even had to explain this to the parishes here in the US that we got married in and where we did our prep (our home parish where we needed permission from) and both priests were quite surprised.
This also brings up the question: will the parish here in the US be able to notify our baptismal parishes back in the Philippines that we are married? Will they care if they haven't been recording our communion and confirmation anyway?

There is the law, and there is practice. I know that we keep those records very seriously, and for centuries, here.
